# Word for "temporarily defeated"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that expresses the meaning of the phrase "temporarily defeated" in a mild manner. This is to be applied on someone whose bid got displaced by a higher bidder in an auction that has not yet ended.

```
The <temporarily defeated> bidder...
```

Comment: Why not *outbid* or *overbid*?

Comment: Because I am looking for an adjective to describe the person. `The <outbid> bidder...` certainly doesn't sound right.

Comment: I suggest vice-president!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps **[trailing](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trailing)**

> (intransitive) to be falling behind in a race or competition: *the favourite is trailing at the last fence*

It has the advantage of suggesting that a rally may occur.

Answer (score 6):

In this instance, you could use "overtaken"

> The overtaken bidder

Which means that someone else out-bid them, but that they still could retake their place as the highest bidder.

[Overtake](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overtake)

> o·ver·take [oh-ver-teyk]
>
> verb (used with object), o·ver·took,
>   o·ver·tak·en, o·ver·tak·ing.
>
> 1. to catch up with in traveling or pursuit; draw even with: By taking a cab to the next town, we managed to overtake and board the train.
> 2. to catch up with and pass, as in a race; move by: He overtook the leader three laps from the finish.
> 3. to move ahead of in achievement, production, score, etc.; surpass: to overtake all other countries in steel production.
> 4. to happen to or befall someone suddenly or unexpectedly, as night, a storm, or death: The pounding rainstorm overtook them just outside
>      the city.
>
> verb (used without object), o·ver·took, o·ver·tak·en,
>   o·ver·tak·ing.
>
> 1. to pass another vehicle: Never overtake on a curve.

Answer (score 4):

A temporary *setback*, might suggest a sort of pause in the bidding .. With the bidder going to come back more resolute.

Comment: Setback was my choice too.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case the bidder was **outbid**, an easy phrase to use in most situations like this is the word **passed**.

The largest auction site in the world uses outbid for temporarily falling behind.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*frustrated* I think, has that sense of being an ongoing condition of being kept from one's objective.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite would be:

> Preempt: to take the place of (something).

It's in common use referring to resource competitions (like bidding).

Similarly:

> Supplant: to take the place of and serve as a substitute for especially by reason of superior excellence or power.

I feel like "supplant" emphasizes more the action of taking the place after conquering (rather than the process of vying for it as in preemption.)

It would be a bit figurative but you could also say

> Dethrone

or

> Depose

which both refer specifically to removing people from positions of power.

Answer (score 0):

Before knowing your context was bidding and not life, I was going to say:

*setback* (n.) or *set back* (v.)

Hadn't not noticed @Josh61 previously posted that.

But in the context of being currently outbid:

*currently outbid* (yes it's two words) or *trailing*